# Unable to resolve place holder in Mockito Unit test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

The Controller that I'm trying to write unit test case for is as follows -

```
@RequestMapping("${rest.base.path}/plugin")
public class Controller {
.
.
.
}
```

The Unit test case is setup -

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @InjectMocks
    Controller dataController;

    @Mock
    PluginService pluginService;


    @Test
    public void createFiles() throws Exception {
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(dataController).build();
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/dc/plugin")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
```

On running the unit test, it's unable to resolve the placeholder **${rest.base.path}** as I'm not loading the Spring Context. I tried setting the **System.setProperty("rest.base.path", "/api")** without any success. Is there anyway I can assign value to that placeholder without removing **@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)**?

Comment: Why don't you just use the Mockito JUnit rule (`@Rule public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();` ) instead of the `@RunWith`.

Comment: How will that resolve the placeholder issue?

Comment: Instead of using Mockito directly (and assuming you are using Spring Boot 1.4 or greater) just run it as a regular test, remove the setup for the `MockMvc` and replace `@Mock` with `@MockBean` this will instruct Spring Boot to create a mock of that bean and inject it in the places that use it.

Comment: @davyjones I don't mean to imply that it would.  I'm only querying your objection to removing the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.  There's no reason not to remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is to fill placeholder yourself calling [StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.addPlaceholderValue](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.html#addPlaceholderValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

As the documentation states:

> In a standalone setup there is no support for placeholder values embedded in request mappings. This method allows manually provided placeholder values so they can be resolved.

So, the following simple snippet should work for you

```
public class TestController {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new Controller()).addPlaceHolderValue("rest.base.path", "dc")
            .setControllerAdvice(new ExceptionMapper())
            .setMessageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(new ExtendedObjectMapper())).build();
}

@Test
public void testGet() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/dc/plugin").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)).andExpect(status().isOk());
}}
```

For sure, you can achieve the same autowiring your controller.